# Guess the word with definitions? (nested tuples)

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to create a function that prints a random word, and then its definition only using nested tuples (stated clearly in my assignment that i cannot use anything else…). The problem is that i then need to import this function into another program that makes the user guess the word, and, at the end, print out the definition. I have tried a million things and I cannot seem to get it right. I am not allowed to use class or anything like that, just modules, functions, boolean and nested tuples.

More precisely, I am struggling to create global variables that go together (the random word with the definition) that I can then import into my other program that makes the user guess the word.

```
import time 
import random
from random import randrange

word_list = (('string','Collection of alphabets, words or other characters.'), 
             ('int','Converts any string, bytes-like object or a number to integer and returns.'),
            ('boolean',"The Python Boolean type is one of Python's built-in data types. It's used to represent the truth value of an expression."),
             ('print','Output function.'),
            ('tuple','Tuples are used to store multiple items in a single variable. Tuple is one of 4 built-in data types in Python used to store collections of data.'),
             ('list','Lists are used to store multiple items in a single variable. Lists are one of 4 built-in data types in Python used to store collections of data.'))
             
def Programming_Concepts():
  for i in range(0,10):
        i = randrange(len(word_list))
        global word
        word = print (word_list[i][0])
        time.sleep(2)
        global definition
        definition = print (word_list[i][1])
        time.sleep(1)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
         Programming_Concepts()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear to me what your question is. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details; but what is your question -- specifically, why does it not work?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, thanks for your question. Your code runs, and produces a result. If the result is not what you desire/expect, of there is something else you wish to do with your code, can you please describe your expectations more clearly, so we can offer you a targeted solution? Cheers, and good luck.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the `print` function does - it outputs some text to the console, and its return value is `None` - there is no reason to do `word = print(word_list[i][0])`, because `word` will be assigned the value returned from the `print` function, which is `None`. `word_list[i][0]` is already a string, so I think you want to do `word = word_list[i][0]` followed by `print(word)`, or just remove the `word =` part if you don't need the `word` variable.

Comment: @Oli I have just tried that, but the problem is that when I try to print Word outside of the function it doesn’t work… in other words, I’m not sure what to do to make it a global variable that I can then import from my module into another module.

Comment: Just clarifying the task: you say that you will need the user to guess the word, then print the definition - are they just guessing a random word, or do you mean that it prints the definition then they say which word?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the assignment says that it has to be one function that prints the word and its definition, or can it be split into two functions?

Comment: @Oli the user needs to guess a random word (like in hangman), and when guessed the function needs to print out its definition. And yes, apparently it has to be in the same function, but if it is easier to do with 2 functions I will just use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler approach that involves splitting your tasks. Below gives a random word from list and its meaning on each function call in import.

```
import random

def random_word_meaning():
  word_list = (('string','Collection of alphabets, words or other characters.'), 
               ('int','Converts any string, bytes-like object or a number to integer and returns.'),
               ('boolean',"The Python Boolean type is one of Python's built-in data types. It's used to represent the truth value of an expression."),
               ('print','Output function.'),
               ('tuple','Tuples are used to store multiple items in a single variable. Tuple is one of 4 built-in data types in Python used to store collections of data.'),
               ('list','Lists are used to store multiple items in a single variable. Lists are one of 4 built-in data types in Python used to store collections of data.'))
             
  return random.choice(word_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
         word, definition = random_word_meaning()
         print(word)
         print(definition)
```

Comment: Use `random.choice` and directly return the tuple. There's a bunch of unnecessary work here. `def random_word_meaning(): return random.choice(word_list))`

Comment: Edited on @ddejohn's comment.